# Flatten dictionary of strings and dictionaries

Tags: javascript

By a dictionary I mean an object.
For example, there is such a dictionary:

```
dict = {
  "foo": {qty: 1, price: 23},
  "bar": {qty: 7, price: 182}
 }
```

How do i get

```
arr = [["foo", 1, 23],
        ["bar", 7, 182]]
```

Comment: by dictionary, you mean an object?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your input dictionary doesn't appear to be syntactically valid and will throw a syntax error. Can you add a valid input (I suppose you mean object)? Providing your attempt at solving the problem and the issues you faced is also something which is expected to be added when posting a question

Comment: @RameshReddy i came from C# and can confuse object with dictionary. Yes, I meant an object.

Comment: @NickParsons edited the question

Comment: @olegshmel: Have rated your question. Someone had marked it less useful. Don't give up ...Coding is fun... Enjoy. Please check my answer and let me know if you need more help on this or your need any explanation mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Object.values` for that:

```js
const dict = {"foo": {qty: 1,price: 23},"bar": {qty: 7,price: 182}};

const result = Object.entries(dict).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...Object.values(v)]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice answer :) @Ramesh. I am also rating it for other's to benefit from. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

First get the keys of two objects using `Object.keys(dictionary)`, Then use spread operator as shown below to get the desired output.

```js
const dictionary = {
"foo": {qty: 1, price: 23},
"bar": {qty: 7, price: 182}
}

const keys = Object.keys(dictionary);
//console.log(keys);

const dict1 = [keys[0],...Object.values(dictionary["foo"])];
const dict2 = [keys[1],...Object.values(dictionary["bar"])];

            
const output = [dict1,dict2];
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hope this helps :) Do please rate by clicking the tick sign next to my answer and also accept the answer for other's to also benefit from :) Happy Coding

Comment: Data is dynamic, this answer doesn't quite work for me

Comment: No Problem. See @Ramesh Reddy's answer. That will work in all cases :)